# Scanning lists inside dictionary

Tags: python

```
J={'Sam': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'Bil': ['d', 'e', 'f']}
```

This is how can I print an element.

```
J['Sam'][1]
```

I have above dictionary. The program prompts for user input. The user has to enter second value of list e.g. `b` or `e` or anything else (but always second) because this dictionary is too big in real.

So I want the element just before user input get printed.

e.g. if the user inputs `b`,
  I should get output `a`;
     if the user inputs `e`,
  I should get output `d`.

I am just curious about manipulating data. And definitely, I am learning basics I have to design a networking simulator. So this is just to get ready for that.

Comment: this is not a "write teh code pretty plz!" site. show us your code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP expect us to solve the problem and write all the code.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why your data is in a `dict` like that when you're doing a lookup that doesn't involve its keys.  There are a number of easy ways to accomplish what you're trying to do but to avoid an XY problem you should explain *why* you're trying to do this.

Comment: This is not a problem. Just basic manipulation of lists. I am not asking to design a controller for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go back to basics because it's not clear why you're doing what you're doing.

A `dict` is a great data structure when you're doing *lookups* - in your case you can do `J['Sam']` and get back the value associated with Sam - a `list`.  It's fast.  Cool.

A `dict` is a clunky data structure when you have to iterate over it.  It does not maintain order.  It cannot be indexed in to.  It's slow.  Boo.

But let's move on, let's assume your `J` has to be in that format.  That's fine.  Notice that you're asking to do a different lookup than your `dict` is set up for - given a key `'b'`, what is the value directly before it (in some lists somewhere, whatever).  So one way is to just make another `dict` that has the lookups you need.

```
{k:v for v,k,_ in J.values()} # in python 2, use J.itervalues() instead
Out[3]: {'b': 'a', 'e': 'd'}
```

Easy peasy: now you can look up the previous element using this new `dict`.

But this only works cleanly if your first `dict` is static; if you're changing it a bunch, you have to keep updating this lookup dict before doing every lookup.  Not the best.

You could alternatively just run through all of your values every time looking for a target - let's say you want the value before `'e'`.

```
next(x for x,y,z in J.values() if y == 'e')
Out[5]: 'd'
```

This uses [`next`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) on a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) that will give us the first list element when the second list element `== 'e'`.  The cool thing about `next` is that you can specify what you want if your generator expression is exhausted:

```
next((a for a,b,c in J.values() if b == 'blah'), 'not found')
Out[6]: 'not found'
```

Note that all of these answers use [tuple unpacking](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html) which is just a syntactic nicety.  I could just as easily have written the bottom one as

```
next(x[0] for x in J.values() if x[1] == 'e')
```

Same thing, really.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
J = {'Sam': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'Bil': ['d', 'e', 'f']}

def lookup(key, dictionary):
    for value in dictionary.values(): #in Python2, use itervalues() instead
        if key in value:
            return value[value.index(key) - 1]
    else: 
        print('key not found')

>>> lookup('e', J)
'd'
>>> lookup('c', J)
'b'
```

Note that this method will return the last value if the key given is a first value.

```
>>> lookup('a', J)
'c'
```

The above assumes that the lists could be however long and the idea is to find the element preceding the key in the list.

If you the positioning of the lookup element is always the same:

```
def lookup(key, dictionary):
    for value in dictionary.values(): #Python 2, use itervalues() instead
        if key == value[1]:
            return value[0]
    else: 
        print('key not found')
```

And usage:

```
>>> lookup('b', J)
'a'
>>> lookup('e', J)
'd'
>>> lookup('c', J)
key not found
```